# Заполнение столбца датафрейма строковыми данными из другого столбца, а не списком

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, re

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Vv_qryIV448lCKlNyeD4VniFB06oe7L/view?usp=sharing).

В нем необходимо в столбце 'body' слова, начинающиеся с символа "#", записать с столбец 'rubric' строкой. Если этих слов несколько, то они должны быть разделены запятой.

Я использую разные коды, например:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('SB.csv', encoding = 'utf-16')

df['rubric'] = df['body'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('#\w+', x))
df.head()
```

передает в столбец датафрейма список из одного или нескольких элементов, а нужна строка. Пример выдачи такого кода:

> [#В_закладки_Skillbox, #Skillbox_дизайн]

Код

```
def rubric(x):
    all_tag = re.findall('#\w+', x)
    for tag in all_tag:
        return tag
            
df['rubric'] = df['body'].apply(lambda x: rubric(x))
df.head(19)
```

передает в столбец строку, но всегда только из одного элемента. Пример выдачи такого кода:

> [#В_закладки_Skillbox]

Желаемый результат:

> #В_закладки_Skillbox, #Skillbox_дизайн

Comment: ', '.join(['#В_закладки_Skillbox', '#Skillbox_дизайн']) == '#В_закладки_Skillbox, #Skillbox_дизайн'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```py
df['rubric'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'#\w+').str.join(', ')
```

Если есть необходимость найти только отдельные слова, можно использовать следующие варианты:

```py
df['rubric'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'(?<!\S)#\w+').str.join(', ') # после пробелов
df['rubric'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'\B#\w+').str.join(', ') # после пунктуации и пробелов
```

Если в хэштегах есть дефисы, используйте

```py
df['rubric'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'#[\w-]+').str.join(', ')
```

Пример использования:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'body':['Some #word #here', 'Текст #вася_пупкин, #zmej-gorynych,#baba-yaga', 'Wiadomość od #łajdak123']})
df['rubric'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'#[\w-]+').str.join(', ')
df['rubric']
#  0                                #word, #here
#  1    #вася_пупкин, #zmej-gorynych, #baba-yaga
#  2                                  #łajdak123
```